# Multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4

I have an application which runs 2 worker threads separate from the main GUI thread.

### Thread 1:

- needs to send some data to thread 2 every 100 ms.
- sleeps for 10ms in each loop of its run.

Header:

```
class thread1:public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    thread1();
    ~thread1();

signals:
    void wakeThread2();
    void sendValue(int);
    void sleepThread2();

protected:
    void run();

private:
    volatile bool stop;
    int data;
};
```

Implementation:

```
thread1::thread1():stop(false),data(0)
{

}

void thread1::run()
{
    while(!stop)
    {
        ++data;
        if(data==1000)
            data = 0;
        cout<<"IN THREAD 1 with data = "<<data<<endl;
        emit sendValue(data);
        emit wakeThread2();
        emit sleepThread2();
        msleep(10);

    }
}
```

### Thread 2

Header:

```
class thread2:public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    thread2();
    ~thread2();

private slots:
    void receiveValue(int);
    void Sleep();

protected:
    void run();

private:
    volatile bool stop;
    int data;
};
```

Implementation:

```
thread2::thread2():stop(false),data(0)
{

}

void thread2::run()
{
    if(!stop)
        cout<<"IN THREAD..............2  with data = "<<data<<endl;
}

void thread2::receiveValue(int x)
{
    data = x;
}

void thread2::Sleep()
{
    msleep(100);
}
```

### MainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    t1 = new thread1;
    t2 = new thread2;

    QObject::connect(t1,SIGNAL(wakeThread2()),t2,SLOT(start()));
    QObject::connect(t1,SIGNAL(sendValue(int)),t2,SLOT(receiveValue(int)));
    QObject::connect(t1,SIGNAL(sleepThread2()),t2,SLOT(Sleep()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_startT1_clicked()
{
    t1->start();
}
```

### Output:

```
IN THREAD 1 with data = 1
IN THREAD..............2  with data = 1
IN THREAD 1 with data = 2
IN THREAD 1 with data = 3
IN THREAD 1 with data = 4
IN THREAD 1 with data = 5
IN THREAD 1 with data = 6
IN THREAD 1 with data = 7
IN THREAD 1 with data = 8
IN THREAD 1 with data = 9
IN THREAD 1 with data = 10
IN THREAD 1 with data = 11
IN THREAD..............2  with data = 2
IN THREAD 1 with data = 12
IN THREAD 1 with data = 13
IN THREAD 1 with data = 14
IN THREAD 1 with data = 15
IN THREAD 1 with data = 16
IN THREAD 1 with data = 17
IN THREAD 1 with data = 18
IN THREAD 1 with data = 19
IN THREAD 1 with data = 20
```

---

The data in thread 2 is not getting updated with the latest value of thread 1 and the GUI window is totally frozen. Please let me know if there is better/more efficient way to implement multi thread applications with Qt and to communicate between threads.

**EDIT : ACCORDING TO LUCA** the Thread1 remains almost the same...while Thread2.h looks like this

**Thread2.h**

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class Thread2 : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Thread2();
    ~Thread2();
    void startThread();
public slots:
    void receiveData(int);
protected:
    void run();
private:
    volatile bool stop;
    int data;
    QTimer *timer;

};
```

and Implementation is....**Thread2.cpp**..

```
#include "thread2.h"

Thread2::Thread2():stop(false),data(0)
{
    timer = new QTimer;
    QObject::connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(start()));
}

Thread2::~Thread2()
{
    delete timer;
}

void Thread2::receiveData(int x)
{
    this->data = x;
}

void Thread2::run()
{
    cout<<"thread 2 .........data  =  "<<data<<endl;
}

void Thread2::startThread()
{
    timer->start(100);
}
```

and the **mainwindow.cpp** looks like this...

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    t1 = new Thread1;
    t2 = new Thread2;

    QObject::connect(t1,SIGNAL(sendData(int)),t2,SLOT(receiveData(int)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_start_thread1_clicked()
{
    t1->start();
    t2->startThread();
}
```

Comment: Btw, subclassing QThread is probably not what you want. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13332951/856199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me data is actually updated. But thread 1 is 10 times faster than thread 2. When you emit the Sleep signal, thread 2 is put to sleep for 100ms, which makes it unable to process other signals. Those will be placed in a queue and processed as soon as the control returns to the event loop. Then you'll see the message with data updated.

The specification anyway is quite weird for me: I read "thread 1 needs to send data to thread 2 every 100 ms....", but I see you do it every 10ms, but then you say "thread 1 itself sleeps for 10ms in each loop of its run". What is thread 1 supposed to do for the rest of the time?

EDIT: I don't think this is exactly what you wanted, but still I'm not completely sure I understand what you're looking for. Not a complete or good implementation, just to give the idea:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>

class Thread1 : public QThread
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit Thread1() :
      data(0) {
      // Do nothing.
   }

   void run() {
      while (true) {
         data++;
         qDebug("Done some calculation here. Data is now %d.", data);
         emit dataChanged(data);
         usleep(10000);
      }
   }

signals:
   void dataChanged(int data);

private:
   int data;
};

class Thread2 : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit Thread2() {
      timer = new QTimer;
      connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processData()));
      timer->start(100);
   }

   ~Thread2() {
      delete timer;
   }

public slots:
   void dataChanged(int data) {
      this->data = data;
   }

   void processData() {
      qDebug("Processing data = %d.", data);
   }

private:
   QTimer* timer;
   int data;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

   Thread1 t1;
   Thread2 t2;
   qApp->connect(&t1, SIGNAL(dataChanged(int)), &t2, SLOT(dataChanged(int)));
   t1.start();

   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

The output is:

```
Done some calculation here. Data is now 1.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 2.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 3.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 4.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 5.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 6.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 7.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 8.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 9.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 10.
Processing data = 10.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 11.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 12.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 13.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 14.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 15.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 16.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 17.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 18.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 19.
Processing data = 19.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 20.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 21.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 22.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 23.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 24.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 25.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 26.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 27.
Done some calculation here. Data is now 28.
Processing data = 28.
...
```

Beware that Thread2 actually is the main thread (i.e. UI thread) of your application. Move the object to a different thread if you need it.

Comment: @Luca...ya thread1 is a paint thread updating images from a live camera every 10 ms and that information is passed on to another instrument which is little slower than the camera getting updates per 100 ms..its true I am sending the info to thread2 every 10 ms but since thread2 is sleeping for 100 ms so i assume the info is not getting updated...is there any other way to implement this design?...the following is what i wanted to do...i have just reduced the problem to simple threads...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627084/class-design-in-qt-for-inter-thread-communication

Comment: The information is queued and copied. If this is not what you want then simply process current data every 100ms in thread 2.

Comment: I added some code to try to explain better my last comment. Don't know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: ...ya thats what i am looking for...i edited my question according to your suggestion...please do have a look whether i did it the correct way...as of now its working fine in my system...